# Why is the root user home dir isn't under /home

Tags: linux, partitioning, filesystems, home-directory

I know one of the reasons of /root not being under /home is because /home might be a different partition and we want to be able to log into the user root always.

What are some of the other reasons for this? Ty!

Comment: this is probably more suitable in [unix.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Anecdotic:) when harddrives were much smaller, `/home` used to be on a different partition (or even disk)... and was mounted comparatively *late*, when the system went "up".

In contrast, `/root` was deemed essential for system maintenance purposes, and thus had to be present at any rate - even when the "user disk" wasn't mounted.

So it's probably just ancient "best practice" nowadays.